# How can I use Numba for Pytorch tensors?

Tags: pytorch, tensor, numba

I am new to Numba and I need to use Numba to speed up some Pytorch functions. But I find even a very simple function does not work :(

```
import torch
import numba

@numba.njit()
def vec_add_odd_pos(a, b):
    res = 0.
    for pos in range(len(a)):
        if pos % 2 == 0:
            res += a[pos] + b[pos]
    return res

x = torch.tensor([3, 4, 5.])
y = torch.tensor([-2, 0, 1.])
z = vec_add_odd_pos(x, y)
```

But the following error appears

```
def vec_add_odd_pos(a, b):
    res = 0.
    ^

This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 0: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'torch.Tensor'>
- argument 1: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'torch.Tensor'>
```

Can anyone help me? A link with more examples would be also appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have even more complicated examples? Otherwise I'd suggest `torch.sum(x[::2] + y[::2])`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pytorch now exposes an interface on GPU tensors which can be consumed by numba directly:

`numba.cuda.as_cuda_array(tensor)`

The test script provides a few usage examples: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/test/test_numba_integration.py

Comment: Hey, can you give an example of how to use: numba.cuda.as_cuda_array(tensor)

Answer (score 10):

As others have mentioned, numba currently doesn't support torch tensors, only numpy tensors. However there is [TorchScript](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html), which has a similar goal. Your function can then be rewritten as such:

```py
import torch

@torch.jit.script
def vec_add_odd_pos(a, b):
    res = 0.
    for pos in range(len(a)):
        if pos % 2 == 0:
            res += a[pos] + b[pos]
    return res

x = torch.tensor([3, 4, 5.])
y = torch.tensor([-2, 0, 1.])
z = vec_add_odd_pos(x, y)
```

Beware: although you said your code snippet was just a simple example, for loops are really slow and running TorchScript might not help you much, you should avoid them at any cost and only use then when no other solution exist. That being said, here's how to implement your function in a more performant way:

```py
def vec_add_odd_pos(a, b):
    evenids = torch.arange(len(a)) % 2 == 0
    return (a[evenids] + b[evenids]).sum()
```

Comment: _for loops are really slow._ Isn't that exactly what numba is trying to solve, i.e., situations where you have a certain logic that is impossible (or very awkward) to vectorize? Implementing for loops in numba certainly isn't slow. If for loops are slow in TorchScript its goals aren't really similar to numba.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase it: for loops might still not be as fast as a vectorized alternative*. They will most likely be sped up (on par with numba), however without knowing the inner workings of TorchScript, I'd assume that not all loops can/will be parallelized in the same way that many native PyTorch functions are. Therefore, I would suggest to use native vectorized functions whenever possible. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

`numba` supports numpy-arrays but not torch's tensors. There is however a bridge [`Tensor.numpy()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.numpy):

> Returns self tensor as a NumPy ndarray. This tensor and the returned
> ndarray share the same underlying storage. Changes to self tensor will
> be reflected in the ndarray and vice versa.

That means you have to call jitted functions as:

```
...
z = vec_add_odd_pos(x.numpy(), y.numpy())
```

If `z` should be a `torch.Tensor` as well, [`torch.from_numpy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.from_numpy.html#torch.from_numpy) is what we need:

> Creates a Tensor from a numpy.ndarray.
>
> The returned tensor and ndarray share the same memory. Modifications
> to the tensor will be reflected in the ndarray and vice versa. The
> returned tensor is not resizable.
> ...

For our code that means

```
...
z = torch.from_numpy(vec_add_odd_pos(x.numpy(), y.numpy()))
```

should be called.

Comment: I am not sure that when you are looking for performance, converting to arrays is the goto. But worth a shot if you are out of options!

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a little bit on @pixelou's answer: Since [this PR](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/11914), pytorch indeed implements numba's [cuda array interface](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cuda/cuda_array_interface.html), but how exactly can that be used for jit compilation with numba?

If I understand it correctly, numba comes with different jit modes, and they differ in what tensors/arrays are supported.

- The regular `@numba.jit` (or `njit` for "nopython" mode) compiles to regular native code, and has support for passing in numpy arrays.
- The special `@numba.cuda.jit` compiles to CUDA, and has [support for passing in CUDA tensors](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cuda/cuda_array_interface.html#consuming-arrays), specifically via `DeviceNDArray` instances obtained from `as_cuda_array` or `from_cuda_array_interface`.

From a pytorch perspective this makes it a bit tricky, because depending on whether a tensor is a CPU or GPU tensor, a different numba function has to be used. I came up with a little recipe that supports both CPU and GPU tensors. I'll demonstrate it on a slightly different example that I happened to work on.

```py
# Small example of a "varying length delay line". Basically this is the function
# we want to speed up. Note that there are no type annotations on the two input
# tensors, because depending on which jit path we take, these are different kind
# of arrays (either numpy or CUDA).

def _delay_line_impl(samples, delays):
    # Basically `delays` is an integer array, and we basically want to mix
    # each `samples[i]` with the sample specified by `delays[i]`.
    for i in range(len(samples)):
        delay = int(delays[i].item())
        index_delayed = i - delay
        if index_delayed < 0:
            index_delayed = 0

        samples[i] = 0.5 * (samples[i] + samples[index_delayed])

# Now produce two different jit versions of that function, one for CPU and one for
# GPU tensors.
_delay_line_numba_cpu = numba.njit()(_delay_line_impl)
_delay_line_numba_cuda = numba.cuda.jit(_delay_line_impl)

# Finally, we introduce a convenience wrapper with proper types that delegates to
# the underlying jit functions.
def delay_line(samples: torch.Tensor, delays: torch.Tensor):
    if samples.is_cuda:
        samples_view = numba.cuda.as_cuda_array(samples.detach())
        delays_view = numba.cuda.as_cuda_array(delays.detach())
        # Totally arbitrary numbers here, for details refer to:
        # https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cuda/kernels.html#kernel-invocation
        blockspergrid = 1
        threadsperblock = 4
        _delay_line_numba_cuda[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](samples_view, delays_view)  # type: ignore
    else:
        _delay_line_numba_cpu(samples.detach().numpy(), delays.detach().numpy())  # type: ignore
```

**Caveat**: Note that in general it is necessary to `detach` tensors that are passed to the numba function. Otherwise we will get a runtime error if the input tensors comes with `requires_grad=True`. This means that it is impossible to support autograd backwards passes when using numba, which is a similar limitation writing [custom C++ extensions](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html#backward-pass). If backprop is required, one has to manually implement an accompanying `backwards` functions (possibly also powered by numba), and than wrap both forward + backward into a
`torch.autograd.Function` as demonstrated in
[here in the C++ extension tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html#using-your-extension).

In case you are running into errors `libNVVM cannot be found` during the CUDA jit compilation: Numba needs to find the CUDA shared libraries during jit compilation. The resolution logic is documented under [Setting CUDA Installation Path](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cuda/overview.html#setting-cuda-installation-path). In my case I head to export `CUDA_HOME` to point to my CUDA installation.

---

FYI, I also benchmarked various variations of the above function:

- plain python: Just calls `_delay_line_impl` directly as it is.
- torchscript: Wrapped into `@torch.jit.script`.
- numba: Wrapped as shown above.
- cpp: That's a custom C++ extension, basically a literal translation of the Python code to C++.

Each method was benchmarked with the input tensors either residing on CPU or GPU. Results (median of 100 executions, each with a sample buffer size of 1024):

```
╭──────────────┬──────────┬────────────────────╮
│ Method       │ Device   │   Median time [ms] │
├──────────────┼──────────┼────────────────────┤
│ plain_python │ CPU      │             13.980 │
│ torchscript  │ CPU      │              5.926 │
│ numba        │ CPU      │              0.016 │
│ cpp          │ CPU      │              8.918 │
│ plain_python │ GPU      │             47.280 │
│ torchscript  │ GPU      │             47.722 │
│ numba        │ GPU      │              0.228 │
│ cpp          │ GPU      │             32.888 │
╰──────────────┴──────────┴────────────────────╯
```

Numba seems to be very fast. I don't quite understand yet why C++ doesn't match its performance, following-up on that in a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75580832/1804173).

Comment: I'm confused the table showed `GPU` slower than `CPU`

Comment: @hhh Yes, I was a bit surprised by that initially as well, but in retrospect it is probably expected in this case. Note that there are quite a lot of questions on SO that are surprised by this effect see e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53325418/1804173). In general, operations that cannot be computed in parallel on the GPU entirely may not benefit from being partially computed on the GPU. This might be one of these cases.