# Why is PyTorch C++ extension much slower than its equivalent numba version?

Tags: c++, pytorch, numba, torch

I have been experimenting with various options to speed up some for-loop-heavy-logic in PyTorch. The two obvious options to do so are either using [numba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75580380/1804173) or [writing a custom C++ extension](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html).

As an example I have picked a "variable length delay line" from digital signal processing. This can be written trivially but inefficiently using a plain Python for loop:

```py
def delay_line(samples, delays):
    """
    :param samples: Float tensor of shape (N,)
    :param delays: Int tensor of shape (N,)
    
    The goal is basically to mix each `samples[i]` with the delayed sample
    specified by a per-sample `delays[i]`.
    """
    for i in range(len(samples)):
        delay = int(delays[i].item())
        index_delayed = i - delay
        if index_delayed < 0:
            index_delayed = 0

        samples[i] = 0.5 * (samples[i] + samples[index_delayed])
```

Knowing how bad for loops perform in Python, my hope was that I can get significantly better performance by implementing the same in C++. Following [the tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html), I came up with this literal translation from Python to C++:

```cpp
void delay_line(torch::Tensor samples, torch::Tensor delays) {

  int64_t input_size = samples.size(-1);

  for (int64_t i = 0; i < input_size; ++i) {
    int64_t delay = delays[i].item<int64_t>();
    int64_t index_delayed = i - delay;
    if (index_delayed < 0) {
      index_delayed = 0;
    }

    samples[i] = 0.5 * (samples[i] + samples[index_delayed]);
  }
}
```

I have also taken the Python function and wrapped it into various jit decorators to get numba and torchscript versions of that function (see my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75580380/1804173) for details on the numba wrapping). I then executed my benchmark for all the versions, also depending on whether tensors reside on the CPU or GPU. The results are rather surprising:

```
╭──────────────┬──────────┬────────────────────╮
│ Method       │ Device   │   Median time [ms] │
├──────────────┼──────────┼────────────────────┤
│ plain_python │ CPU      │             13.481 │
│ torchscript  │ CPU      │              6.318 │
│ numba        │ CPU      │              0.016 │
│ cpp          │ CPU      │              9.056 │
│ plain_python │ GPU      │             45.412 │
│ torchscript  │ GPU      │             47.809 │
│ numba        │ GPU      │              0.236 │
│ cpp          │ GPU      │             31.145 │
╰──────────────┴──────────┴────────────────────╯
```

<sub>Notes: sample buffer size was fixed to 1024; results are medians of 100 executions to ignore artifacts from the initial jit overhead; input data creation and moving it to the device is excluded from the measurements; full benchmark script [gist](https://gist.github.com/bluenote10/3370da06204b94995614ed014410f6c2)</sub>

The most notable result: The C++ variant seems to be surprisingly slow. The fact that numba is two orders of magnitude faster indicates that the problem indeed can be solved faster. And the fact that the C++ variant is still pretty close to the know-to-be-slow Python for loop may indicate that something isn't quite right.

I'm wondering what could explain the poor performance of the C++ extension. The first thing that comes to mind is missing optimization. However, I've made sure that the compilation uses optimization. Switching from `-O2` to `-O3` also didn't make a difference.

To isolate the overhead of the pybind11 function call, I have replaced the C++ function with an empty body, i.e., just doing nothing. This reduced the time to 2-3 **μs**, which means that the time really is spend in that particular function body.

Any ideas why I'm observing such a poor performance, and is there anything I could do on the C++ side to match the performance of the numba implementation?

Bonus question: Is it expected that the GPU versions are much slower than the CPU versions?

Comment: Does it matter that `torch::Tensor samples` parameter is being passed in by a copy of its value?

Comment: @Eljay: Good point. I just re-ran with references and it doesn't make a difference. Also I think it only looks like "by copy", but the data itself seems to have reference semantics. At least that's my conclusion because my benchmark script contains a post-condition check that the `samples` tensor actually has been modified in-place as it should have been, and this check holds even when passing "by copy". Some pybind11 magic I guess.

Comment: I do not know what `samples[i]` is exactly nor what `delays[i].item<int64_t>()` actually does, but >1 ms seems horribly slow for such a computation.

Comment: I guess the C++ code does allocations or things like this. Having the compiler output would help a lot or a more reproducible example (including the command-line). As for the GPU code, I do not see how it could automagically speed this up: this is simply not possible. You certainly see host-device communication overheads.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I've updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/bluenote10/3370da06204b94995614ed014410f6c2) to include what is needed for compilation. This is basically just following the tutorial, i.e., using PyTorch's `CppExtension` and compiling with `python setup.py build`. Except for the exact compile command, there is no much information output from the compilation.

Comment: FYI I still have not found a solution to this issue, and decided to raise it as an [upstream issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/114951).